# How to enable SwiftStackAuth in Swift proxy server

Tags: openstack-swift

How do I use SwiftStackAuth for authentication? I wasn't able to find out any instruction on official site:- http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/howto_installmultinode.html

Answer (score 0):

Kartik,

If you meant tempAuth then kindly check [this guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/howto_installmultinode.html) you need to do changes in the proxy-server.conf. The official guide uses Keystone as Auth Backend.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Athul, I was checking the link [link](http://swiftstack.com/docs/admin/middleware/swiftstack_auth.html) along with the [link](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/howto_installmultinode.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm using swauth. I'm trying to use swift as backend for owncloud, the issue is that I'm not able to provide read access to public, especially the videos

Comment: Does container has world readable access? BTW check this http://blog.adityapatawari.com/2014/01/using-openstack-swift-as-owncloud.html  but it uses keystone..